Russian equivalent of "Empty Barrels Make the Most Noise"
The English proverb comes in different versions, which include: Empty vessels make the greatest (the most) sound, An empty barrel makes the greatest sound.
Looking for an idiomatic equivalent used in modern Russian. Renderings which are common on the Web (one was quoted from Dahl's collection) don't really sound evocative (don't ring any bells) to me and possibly to other native Russian speakers as well. They are: пустая бочка пуще гремит, пустая посуда звенит громче, пустые сосуды гремят громче всего, пустая бочка больше всех гремит
The meaning of the proverb is that the less knowledgeable or smart a person is the more are they likely or inclined to sound off on various matters.
If someone has other suggestions, they're welcome in the comments under this post. You're also welcome to cast your vote for reopening the thread by clicking Reopen link below.

Язык длинный - ум короткий

Suggested by V.V.

Can you please clarify the meaning of the proverb and provide a couple of "common renderings" that you consider "not evocative" (and explain why)? There's пустая бочка пуще гремит mentioned in Dahl's collection, is there anything wrong with it?

Yes, that's one of them. But to me this rendering doesn't tell much. I personally haven't come across this proverb in my entire life. It may have been in use in Dahl's time but it doesn't seem to be nowadays. Not in my environment anyway.

@Quassnoi Why have you closed it? What opinion is it based on? I'm looking for alternatives which are used in modern Russian, not in Dahl's Russian. Is this the treatment i get after answering here dozens if not hundreds of questions?

Unfortunately, your question as it stands now lacks any criteria which would allow it to be answered objectively. Anecdotally, I've heard this particular rendition many times, and had your question not specified that you didn't want "common renditions", it would have been my answer. But you're, apparently, looking for answers tailored for "your environment", and we just don't know what it is.

@Quassnoi Where did i say i was looking for answers tailored for "my environment". What i said was that i hadn't heard the equivalent you suggested used in my environment. I'm looking for alternatives and i've made that clearer in the question. If there won't be any, fine. But don't prevent me from finding that out.

First of all, thank you for been an active participant if the community. The technical measure of closing the question is 0 percent about you as a person and 100 percent about the question. It just needs to be answerable by someone who's not familiar with you and your background, is all. Please add any objective criteria, and it will be considered for reopening. Thank you!

@Quassnoi I've added objective criteria: modern Russian. Added equivalents (translations really) which to me aren't evocative. Don't get caught up in the answer i gave to your question, that information wasn't included in my question and therefore couldn't disqualify it.

Anyway, if someone has better suggestions, they're welcome here in the comments

Calling someone "пустозвон" conveys the idea quite succinctly, imho.

@Sergey Slepov Thanks, i did consider this, but this isn't as colorful as the proverb. Another one is пустомеля.

@Quassnoi I would humbly recommend to re-open this question. See no issues with it.

@БаянКупи-ка While "пустозвон" remains in use, in the everyday language they will sooner employ its stronger, obscene synonym пиздобол

@БаянКупи-ка Depending on the context, you may consider the saying "Собака лает, ветер носит."

@Michael_1812: the problem is with "not evocative in modern Russian" part. The direct translation of this proverb is used in books and mentioned in the corpus as late as 2001. I speak modern Russian, have heard it used a lot of times, and to me it's as "evocative" as the Shakespeare's version or its direct counterparts used all over the world. However, op makes the point of not accepting it, based on vague personal opinion. It's ok not to accept or not to upvote posts based on a personal preference, but it's not ok to put opinionated criteria like "not evocative enough" in the question.

"but it's not ok to put opinionated criteria like "not evocative enough" in the question" Who has decided "it is not OK"? Can you refer me to any explicit rule which prohibits this? If not, it would be you who shut down the thread based on your opinion about what is and isn't OK.

@Michael_1812 You're welcome to cast your vote for reopening by clicking  the Reopen link under the original post. It needs 3 more votes. Not sure if it'll be auto-reopened once the target is reached.

@БаянКупи-ка It seems that what is problematic is only "(...) don't really sound evocative to the ear of a modern native Russian speaker". It seems to me easy to address this point so that everybody is fine with your question. For instance, you could remove this controversial judgment (I have no opinion, I am not a Russian native speaker) and ask whether there are other synonymous expressions.

@Bruno Fair enough, i've rephrased it to not sound as generalizing. But i don't see how a sweeping judgement can affect the ability of other users to reply to the question because this is the only meaningful criterion for question validity. And it indeed hasn't affected their ability as transpires from the comments here. It seems that the moderator has taken this personally which is a bad practice in moderating.

Язык длинный — ум короткий. My answer. Баян, nice to see you.

Proverbs should be considered according to their meanings. That's the main idea.

@V.V.  Whoa, that's excellent, thank you. This one is 100% evocative to me. I upvoted your post elsewhere as a sign of appreciation.

@Bruno As is now patently evident the wording of the question wasn't the problem, because the thread wasn't unlocked after the wording had been changed. The problem is personal bias and presumption of the moderator.
